# Перебрать все TextBox расположенные во всех Panel

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть две `Panel`, в каждой из них по пять `TextBox`.

Как в **классе** обратиться к этим текст-боксам расположенных в разных панелях?

Думал, передать в метод коллекцию объектов `Control`, но не работает почему-то.

```
public static void SetColorOfTextBox(Control.ControlCollection control)
{
    foreach (Control c in control)
    {
        if (c is TextBox)
        {
            c.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#383636");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Покажите, как вызываете этот метод, что туда передаёте. `static` уберите.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, `SetColorOfTextBox(this);` А зачем убирать `static`?

Comment: `this` - это, вероятно, ссылка на форму. Замени `this` на `this.Controls`.

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать вот так:

```
    private void button_set_color_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SetColorOfTextBox(this.panel1.Controls);
        SetColorOfTextBox(this.panel2.Controls);
    }
```

А можно сделать вот так:

```
    private void button_set_color_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
        {
            if (c is Panel)
            {
                SetColorOfTextBox(c.Controls);
            }
        }
    }
```

Код вашего метода SetColorOfTextBox рабочий и не требует изменений.